# How to place the top ubuntustudio (xfce) panel down?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce

I installed ubuntustudio-desktop and quite happy with it. Since my computer's screen is 12", I would like to put the top panel to the bottom, and delete the bottom dock -- it may save me some desktop space.

How could I place top panel to the bottom?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Right-click with the mouse on the panel that you want to move - Panel - Panel Preferences...
Remove the tick for: Lock panel

Now you can see that at the right and the left side of the panel, a small "handle" has appeared. The far left and the far right icons have shifted a little to the middle because of this. You have to look closely, because the the handles are hardly visible.

Place the mouse pointer on a handle, press the left mouse button and keep it pressed. The pointer has now changed into a little hand. Now you can drag the panel to the place where you want it.

Do you wish to move it from the bottom to the right side of the panel? Then you have to change the Mode from Horizontal into Vertical.

Now drag it to the right.

When you're done, put the tick back for: Lock panel.

Click Close.

Comment: Nice - thanks. Don't know if it helped @Nick, but it helped me. :)